# How to reload a swing JApplet table

Tags: java, swing

I am using swing applet. This applet contain a table which is populated from the DB. It has a button - 'Add row'. When I click on this button a new blank row is added to the table. If I don't fill the row or fill it with wrong data and click 'Save' button a JDialog appears with a validation message. When I click 'OK' on the JDialog , I expect the table to be as before without my newly added row because the row never gets added to the database. However, the newly added row remain on the table as it is. It is confusing for a user.
I tried `fireTableDataChanged()` on `TableSorter` but it did not work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: *"I am using swing applet"* - Please don't, Applets are officially deprecated and are no longer supported

Comment: *"I tried fireTableDataChanged() on TableSorter"* - Since the row has already been added to the `TableModel`, unless you physically delete it or replace all the data in the `TableModel`, why would you expect it to disappear magically by itself?